# lineno from chapter title onwards in two column document

Tags: two-column, lineno

i need to print the line numbers on from chapter title onwards for twocolumn document, but currently it is printing from the start of the text

how to get the line numberes from chapter title onwards? like below

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[switch,modulo]{lineno}
\linenumbers



\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title turn in to maore than one line language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords}



WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:



\section{adkaskldas$^{2^2}$}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\subsection{Sub section Head}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


\section{A head}

\subsection{B Head}


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `linenumbers` environment rather than declaring `\linenumbers` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[switch,modulo]{lineno}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title turn in to maore than one line language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords}

\begin{linenumbers}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:



\section{adkaskldas$^{2^2}$}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\subsection{Sub section Head}

WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:


\section{A head}

\subsection{B Head}


WinEdt's macro language has evolved gradually: as the need arose for actions beyond a predefined set of commands. As a consequence, it is a pretty non-standard language that implements loops and conditional statements with macro functions rather than keywords. Sophisticated macro scripts involving loops and conditional statements are, admittedly, hard to write and read, and it may take some time to become familiar with it. However, WinEdt comes with almost 500 predefined macro functions that can be used to accomplish the most common tasks. Thus you do not have to be a macro language guru to create an interface that launches an external application. The simple macro item:

\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

[image]